# Laravel - Is there any blade directive to check if a variable exists and is set to a specific value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel blade provides many directives, but does it have any shortcut to check if a variable exists and is set to a specific value?

Right now I'm doing something like this : -

```
 @if(isset($request['optional_columns']['reason']) && ($request['optional_columns']['reason'] === "true")
    // Do something ...
 @endif
```

The template is looking really messy right now, I would like to use something which looks neat and clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question :
I solved the problem by creating a custom blade directive.

Created a custom service provider and then defined my own blade directive as follows :

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

    class BladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

            public function register() {

            }

            public function boot() {

                Blade::directive('existsandsetto', function ($expression) {
                    list($var, $value) = explode(',', $expression);
                    $var = trim($var);
                    $value = trim($value);
                    return "<?php if(isset($var) && $var === $value) : ?>";
                });

                Blade::directive('endexistsandsetto', function ($expression) {
                    return '<?php endif; ?>';
                });
            }
        }
```

Usage in Blade template :

```
@existsandsetto($foo, 'bar')
  // $foo exists and is set to 'bar' 
@endexistsandsetto
```

- Don't forget to register the custom service provider.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest your `@if` directive within a an [`@isset` directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures).

```
@isset($request['optional_columns']['reason'])
  @if ($request['optional_columns']['reason'] === 'true')
    // Do something
  @endif
@endisset
```

Or you could define a [custom blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade):

```php
Blade::if('setTrue', function($var) {
  return isset($var) && $var === 'true';
});
```

```
@setTrue($request['optional_columns']['reason'])
  // Do something
@endsetTrue
```

Comment: I have solved the problem  using custom blade directives. Thanks for the help.